# convert HEX STRING to Binary and Right Shift 22 and with 0F

Tags: python, binary, hex

```
print(bin(int("3478e392", 16))[0:] >> 22)
```

> convert to binary is 3478e392 = 00110100011110001110001110010010

Is there any way to convert HEX STRING to Binary, Right Shift 22 and then logical-and with 0F?
The result should return decimal 1

Comment: You simply forgot "and with 0f"... see below.

Comment: bin() converts to binary string... you can't shift that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> print ((int("3478e392",16)>>22)&0xf)
1
```